# Split edges in SUMO must be specified in traci setRoute?

Tags: sumo

i have a given network and i want to set different speed limits per edge.
i use the sumo functionality as mentioned here https://sumo.dlr.de/docs/Networks/PlainXML.html#road_segment_refining

so if the network was with road e1 leading to e2. i split e1 at pos 100
now i have a network with e1,e1.100,e2

currently I'm having issues with setting the route [e1,e2],
traci.exceptions.TraCIException: Route replacement failed
i want to use traci setRoute but without indicating e1.100. is it possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, not directly. The route always needs to contain all edges the car is going to drive (except for junction internal edges). You could however call traci.simulation.findRoute beforehand or use traci.vehicle.setTarget if there is only one route (or the desired route is the fastest) to your destination.

Comment: i wonder then what is the usage of the splits, if they act as a whole new edge then why not just specify a new edge? what is the advantage of using the splits and not edges?

is there some other option to set max speed limit per position on edge?

Comment: If you use a split you do not need to define an additional node yourself and all the parameters for the two edges generated by the split will be identical (except for the ones you change of course). It really is only a helper in network creation. The simulation itself does not care.